# unable to send email via apache james smtp server

Tags: ssl, apache-james

I have setup Apache James server at xxx.xom domain and i am able to receiver message from outer domains like ###@yahoo.com .

bit when trying to send email from xx.com to ##@yahoo.com i am getting :

on thunder bird client :
550 5.1.1 Unknown user

on server --

**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Client requested protocol SSLv3 not enabled**
INFO  08:19:43,676 | org.apache.james.protocols.netty.BasicChannelUpstreamHandler | Connection established from 18.204.244.186
INFO  08:19:46,127 | org.apache.james.protocols.netty.BasicChannelUpstreamHandler | Connection closed for 18.204.244.186
INFO  08:19:46,736 | org.apache.james.protocols.netty.BasicChannelUpstreamHandler | Connection established from 18.204.244.186
ERROR 08:19:48,357 | org.apache.james.protocols.netty.BasicChannelUpstreamHandler | Unable to process request
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Client requested protocol SSLv3 not enabled or not supported
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1521)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:528)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:802)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:766)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1219)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:852)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
        at

Comment: SSLv3 has been disabled because of POODLE vulnerability.  Is "18.204.244.186" the client - Thunderbird?

Comment: i tried same with my own java program still i am getting exception --
ERROR 08:28:26,819 | org.apache.james.domainlist.lib.AbstractDomainList | Cannot get IP address(es) for Domain : ****.****.com
ERROR 08:28:26,820 | org.apache.james.domainlist.lib.AbstractDomainList | Cannot get IP address(es) for Domain : ***.****.com
INFO  08:28:26,824 | org.apache.james.transport.mailets.ToRepository | 
Storing mail Mail1590481706350-91a11856-1138-44bc-897e-3b7e4ec7d3d5 in MailRepositoryUrl{value=file://var/mail/relay-denied/}

Comment: yes client is thunder bird also i tired with my java program but still getting errors :

Comment: The domain for which you get "Cannot get IP", is that the domain to which you want to send a message?

Comment: Also: is the Thunderbird up to date?

Comment: yes its same domain and yes thunder bird is updated

Comment: There is no relation between "Cannot get IP address(es)" and "SSLv3 not enabled".  These are two different problems.

Comment: ok then what should i try,

Comment: SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 5ED07AED138E69EAF70AB41AB239E227EBFF92B6107BC2645D171621E37DA6BC
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 19F4B9941FC7E33C0AC1A79D70A311D1EB24AD5D0B2D06726CA37D0CE5236B83BFDA4E67BFDC59CF00ECE70B07A3D8C3
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1590721261
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)

Comment: Is this yet another problem?  "Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)"